# ckeditor toolbar icons and buttons misaligned

Tags: css, ckeditor, toolbar

I am using ckeditor version 4.4.6 and testing it on IE 11 and Chrome 47.

In a simple form the icons and buttons are aligned right.

However in an existing form which uses other classes for display and validation the icons and buttons in the ckeditor toolbar are misaligned.

I found out that the height of the "a.cke_button" was set to 18px. Once it is set to auto the alignment is ok.

How should I react to different places where I use the toolbar and change the height?

Comment: You may use those existing forms with reference some specific class or ID in CSS and it will not be effected in CKEditor

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by going to the config and rearranging the toolbars and removing the toolbar breaks.